# Temporary URL working fine, But the domain when pointed to the site shows CWP HTTP test page

Tags: dns, centos7, vps

I installed CentOS7 on Amazon EC2 instance, I also installed latest version of CWP(CentOS Web Panel). I created a new user 'myuser'. I associated a domain 'myuser.com' with the user. I uploaded the website files into '/home/myuser/public_html/' and I deleted the default HTTP test index.html present in the same directory. Now I can access my website at http://IP_ADDRESS/~myuser
But when I point 'myuser.com' with my server IP - IP_ADDRESS, it shows CWP HTTP test page. I even modified my host file to make 'myuser.com' point to IP_ADDRESS.
It just shows CWP HTTP test page. 
Please someone help me in solving this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got that just googling for "default page cwp"

Take a look here -> http://forum.centos-webpanel.com/apache/default-page-displayed-for-all-domains/

Comment: Thanks @Jon , But  I tried it already and it didn't work for me, So I ended up posting the question here.

Comment: I think you are editing the wrong file. You should edit
the index.html located at /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/admin/tpl/new_account_tpl That would be the master for all users.

Answer (score 0):

For Google compute engine (Maybe same scenario in Amazon) in CWP Setting don't use the same IP that is being used for cwp admin panel. Use the default IP that will be suggesting just below the field of Shared IP in cwp setting.

In google compute VM Instance you'll find two IP's internal and external

For domain name server setting use external IP while in cwp setting change Shared Ip to your internal IP.

After 10-15 minutes use Kproxy to browse your site again should work then.

Answer (score 0):

Its just temporary issue. Clear browsing data. This mainly happens in Google Chrome. As you didnt open http://IP_ADDRESS/~myuser before creating newuser, you could view uploaded files, as you might have opened myuser.com before uploading and after pointing to server IP, you are still seeing default cwp template.